# Why is $.support.cors false in IE 11?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cors, internet-explorer-11, jquery-1.9

Why is `$.support.cors` `false` in IE 11? I'm using jquery 1.9.1 (`$.fn.jquery == '1.9.1'`).

[IE 11 should support cors.](http://caniuse.com/cors)

`$.support.cors` is true in Chrome with the same version of jquery.

Comment: Make sure you're not in Compatibility View or Quirks Mode due to something like a missing doctype header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.support.cors` does return `true` in IE 11, as demonstrated by this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dM8pk/

`X-UA-Compatible` set to `IE=9` disables cors support.

The following will output "true" in IE 11

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('<h1>').text($.support.cors).appendTo($('body'));
});
</script>
</html>
```

But with `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">` will output "false"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"></meta>
    </head>
<body>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('<h1>').text($.support.cors).appendTo($('body'));
});
</script>
</html>
```